# After first click on delegate selector, it refreshes the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates

I am having a serious problem using .delegate in jQuery 1.11

I have a sidebar called  ".local-filters" which opens when I click #consult-filter.
After that, the hidden sidebar from the right appears (named .local-filter) (toggles a class called .active) and ".overlay" (100% height and width div) makes a black background with class ".active"

I used this to make that happen. Also, I want to click on .overlay (black background) and toggle the overlay class to make it visual disappear.

```
$(document).delegate('#consult-filter, .overlay, .cerrar filtros','click',function(){
  $(".local-filters").toggleClass('active');
  $("body").toggleClass('menu-active');
  return false;
});
```

I read a lot of articles and read something about bubble spreading, but I don't know actually what is happening.

Everything is working correctly, but I don't know why in the second click I made to this element, it automatically refreshes the entire page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a page refresh / reload or link to reload the page anywhere?  Might want to put some sort of debugging on that if so.

Comment: No, actually the button Im pressing its not a button, its just a Div.

Comment: That's not going to be a simple one to debug, unfortunately.  It sounds like something is getting a menu link  expanding over it, so when you click the second time, you're clicking what is in essence an invisible link.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: function abrirMenu(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   $(".local-filters").toggleClass('active');
   $(".overlay").toggleClass('active');
    $("body").toggleClass('menu-active');
    return false;
}
$('#filtro-consulta').click(abrirMenu);
$('.overlay.active').click(abrirMenu);
$('.cerrar-filtros').click(abrirMenu);